# Can't find FoodItem with 'id' =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am working on web app development using ruby on rails. I want to make users able to upload images for their favorite food item in a page. I set a route:

```
 get 'add_image', to: 'food_items#add_image', via: :get
```

When the user is on current food item page and click the link which links to add_image_path, the add image method in food_items controller will be called. The method is defined as:

```
def add_image
   @food_item = FoodItem.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     if @food_item.save
        params[:food_images]['avatar'].each do |a|
            @food_image = @food_item.food_images.create!(:avatar=>a)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @food_item, notice: 'Images uploaded successfully' }
     else
         format.html { redirect_to add_image_path}
     end
  end
end
```

The first line of code wouldn't work since my url can't pass an id to the method. How can I reset the routes to include an id? Or how can I pass the current food_item to this method?

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes as:

```
get 'foot_items/:id/add_image' => 'food_items#add_image', :as => ' add_image'
```

and link to as **add_image_path(food_item.id)** 
here food_item.id is the food item id.